# mail not send via SMTP API using sendgrid

Tags: php, sendgrid

Mail not send to user via SMTP using sendgrid.it shows SMTP error

**code**

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net"; // SMTP server

$mail->SMTPSecure = "SSL";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "szdfsdf";
$mail->Password = "sdfsdfsdfsdf";
$mail->Port = "465";

$mail->From = "tests@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Test";

$mail->AddAddress("test@services.in");
$message = "hi how r u in medapps?";
$message = trim($message);
$mail->Subject  = "from test";
$mail->Body     = trim($message);
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Mail triggered to alert the status!";
}
```

**result**

> Mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: Have you tried testing your credentials via telnet? You can see how to test [in this video](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/getting_started_smtp.html). I really hope the username and password you specified is test data...

Comment: Indeed - check your port number for SSL with `nc -w 1 smtp.sendgrid.net 465` command. Server is not listening on that port. However it listens on 25, 587 ports. See [Common SMTP port numbers](http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/59-default-ports-numbers-smtp-pop-imap)

Comment: @JimWright  now i created new api key and password in sendgrip in my account i did not check in telnet because i could not access control panel its protected by admin.

Comment: @sakthi This has nothing to do with your control panel. Look at the video I linked above to test sending an email so you know which host, port, and credentials to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to SendGrid via SMTP using API Keys, you need to use `apikey` [as the username](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/How_Emails_Are_Sent/api_keys.html#-Via-SMTP).

Also, since you just shared that API Key publicly here, you need to destroy it and make a new one. It's no longer secure.

SendGrid does support port 465 for SSL connectiong, but as Jim said, you need to [test your connection](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Troubleshooting/testing_your_connectivity_to_sendgrids_smtp_relay_using_telnet.html) and see if your server is allowing that connection. If not, try a different port as recommended on that article.
I would recommend trying port 587 with a TLS connection.

Comment: above mention api key not in use